# I would like to offer an apology here

Tags: discussion

I posted a question yesterday here, complaining about how unusually buggy the 16.04 LTS release seems to me.

Well, today I have thought about it better. Ubuntu is free, and after some days of some sweat and blood (which, admittedly,  this time were a bit longer than usual) one gets a stable Unix-alike system for the next two years for free. So, it is a bit unfair to all the developers working in it.

So, well, my apologies here where hopefully they will be seen by more or less the same people who saw my post yesterday.

Comment: For penitence, you're hereby sentenced to two years of hard labour in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding :)

Comment: @muru Hahaha. Well, this time I have learned how to report bugs in launchpad and be sure I will do my humble contribution from now on.

Comment: @muru No!  Don't make him install a new non-lts release every 6 months! Show some mercy!

Comment: We all have those moments. You're freely admitting you made a mistake - not everyone manages to do that. Let the post stand as an example to be followed!

Comment: @vidario Ok, I will leave it here.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [is supported here until April of 2021](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) so you get far more than 2 years for your efforts. I agree with [@muru amusing comment.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17651/i-would-like-to-offer-an-apology-here?cb=1#comment36880_17651) We can certainly use all the help we can get providing that support.